# cordova - downgrade the iOS version

Tags: ios, cordova

I am developing using `cordova` 6.4.0 and `cordova-ios` 4.3.1. I experienced occasional app freeze with no error message from `xcode`. After some reading, I want to tried downgrade to `cordova-ios` 4.1.1 to see if that resolve the issue.

How can I downgrade my `cordova-ios`?

Answer (score 5):

Try to remove current ios platform and then add another version like this:

`cordova platform add ios@x.x.x`

so in your case it will be:

```
cordova platform add ios@4.1.1
```